# Switching Monitors Between Computers

Tags: multiple-monitors

I've got two computers and four monitors. The monitors are arranged in an inverted T using a monitor tree. I have one computer hooked up to the the three monitors in a line along the bottom. I have a second computer connected to the forth monitor above the other three. I'm using ShareMouse Pro to allow both computers to share the same keyboard and mouse.

Problem is that I want to be able to swap the center monitor and the top monitor connected to the second computer. A normal KVM won't work, those are typically used to connect multiple computers to the same monitor and switch between them. Plus, I don't need to switch keyboard or mouse, just the video.

To help clarify, I have computer A connected to monitor A and computer B connected to monitor B.

```
A -> A
B -> B
```

I want to hit a button and have computer A connect to monitor B and computer B connect to monitor A.

```
A -> B 
B -> A
```

Is there anything that can help me or am i going to have to jury rug something together?

Comment: 1) How are you connecting the video output from the PCs to the monitors; VGA/DB-15,  DVI, HDMI, or DisplayPort? 2) Which OS do you use (since ShareMousePro works for multiple OS)? Please click [edit] to enhance your question with this essential information.

Comment: It's not really that too relevant. I've got multiple input and output options and any solution should be platform agnostic since it is just swapping video sources. I only mention MouseShare to point out i don't need to switch keyboard and mouse.

Comment: Knowing how you connect the video output from the PCs to the monitors A & B (VGA/DB-15, DVI, HDMI, or DisplayPort) is essential to the solution.  Please click [edit] to enhance your question with this essential information.   https://www.amazon.com/StarTech-com-Matrix-Video-Switch-Splitter/dp/B0058DO4TC is a VGA-specific solution, for example.